# How to config xdebug in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: php, xdebug

I am trying to enable autostart for xdebug in php5 so it stops on errors when phpstorm debug is on.

Problem is I cant find the [XDEBUG] section in `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini` . I know that xdebug is on from my phpinfo.

Also tried `/etc/php5/apache2/conf/20-xdebug.ini` but contains a single line, no config params here either.

Comment: please post your phpinfo related to xdebug

Answer (score 0):

there is a tutorial right [here](http://xdebug.org/docs/install):

It's official. Try it and tell us when did you stuck